# Button changes form textarea input by button id

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, cordova, dreamweaver

I want to add additional buttons to a form to expand keyboard input into a a textarea.   The button characters include unicode combinations for native american languages.

```
var newtext = document.myform.inputtext.value;
document.myform.outputtext.value += newtext;
```

Bascially I'm having a hard time figuring out how to change inputtext to change with the button id.    All the buttons are within a

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

t̕  igʷicid   Thank you

Visit http://jsfiddle.net/dsienko/a2YmL/

The ultimate goal is a Phone Texting App.  I'm using Dreamweaver and Phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to append right value to the input field.

In case my interpretation is correct, you have a problem because function addText doesn't know which button was clicked.

A really bad solution would be to give it a parameter equal to button's value. For example

```
<input type="button" id="c-wedge" onClick="addtext('č');" value="č" />
```

It makes you duplicate values, and we all know that duplication is just bad.

A better solution would be to have one function, which will know who called it. This is achievable by passing keyword this to the function.

```
<input type="button" id="c-wedge" onClick="addtext(this);" value="č" />

function addtext(that) {

    var nexttest = that.value;
    document.myform.outputtext.value += newtext;
}
```

This is slightly better, because there is know only one function which handles all buttons, but every button needs attribute onClick, so it can get even better. It would be really great if Javascript were placed in only one location.

If you create a special div and make it contain all your buttons and nothing else, you can do the following:

```
document.getElementById('lut-btn').onclick = function (e) {
    var dest = e.target;
    document.myform.outputtext.value += dest.value;
};
```

This little code snippet tries to find div which contains all buttons and registers a click event handler. This works because any element inside of this div will trigger a click event, which will be handled by the registered function. Though you have to take into consideration that better ways of registering event handlers exist and you should explore them.

This is by no means a full list, but it should be an adequate starting point.

Comment: Perfect!    I used the first bit of code and modified the buttons to add (this).   I could tell what the problem was, but not the right solution.    t̕  igʷicid ti dsyaʔyaʔ.   Thank you my friend.